# WebdriverIO : driver.getContext() returns native app from the mobile browser view

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, webdriver-io, appium-android

My app is the hybrid app, when I click on the link it opens the mobile browser and launch the url. I need to get the url and verify it against the data.

When I use
driver.getUrl() returns Method not implemented

When I use
driver.getContext() it returns Native_App

How could I get the url and complete my test?

[image]

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: I'm able to proceed without switching to web view and back to native view

Answer (score 1):

You should switch to the WEB_VIEW context first:

`driver.switch_to.context['WEB_VIEW_chrome]`

then for return to the application:

`driver.switch_to.context['NATIVE_APP]`

Return all available context in list:

`driver.contexts`

Return the current context:

`driver.context`

NOTE: web_view is always the last key in the list, so you can always change the context to webview (Firefox,Chrome,Safari) with this:

```
contexts = driver.contexts
driver.switch_to.contexts[-1]
```